# How to modify, add ,avoid throttling policies limitation in Outlook office 365 online

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to synchronize my application's calendar with user's outlook calendar. I subscribe each user's credentials with exchange server using exchange push subscriptions.

End users use both on premises (Exchange 2010 ) and Outlook office 365 online exchange services.If client is unsubscribed in any occasion I re subscribe the client by checking the duration between two time stamps.This is done by Quartz scheduler.

Some how there are some application related exceptions ,Thus the client tries to resubscribe with the exchange again.But problem is ,at one point exchange server not allows to subscribe the user again  due the limitation in throttling policy. It throws "server busy" error in response and asks me to check it later.

I did some search about throttling policies in Exchange .I got to know that i can alter or add new throttling policies using Exchange management shell in on-premises Server .But i couldn't find anything related to office 365.In fact i saw some threads some people says that Exchange management shell are not available in office 365.

My questions are

1. How can i modify or add new policies to Outlook office 365?
2. What is the best way to avoid reaching the throttling policies limitation?I mean if could get the applied policies and related values before subscribing or after first subscription or after first synchronization ,i can limit the client from sending request frequently .

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I don't think you can change O365 policies.  This would be harmful to the multi-tenant nature if O365.  Best way to avoid being throttled is to use impersonation.

Comment: Thank you.Could you please elaborate more about applying impersonation?

Comment: Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722377(v=exchg.150).aspx